# ViewModel with PreferenceFragmentCompat

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx, android-viewmodel, preferencefragmentcompat

I have a PreferenceFragmentCompat that I would like to use together with a corresponding ViewModel class. Is it doable?

The fragment is currently attached to an androidx AppCompatActivity and it works as intended. However, I would like to display the values of my Preferences under their summaries. Traditionally I would do all data manipulation inside the PreferenceFragment but I was made aware that google is suggesting the MVP architectural pattern.

This question might sound quite noob but I am still trying to get my head around the Jetpack after being away from android development for the past 3 years

The classes/files that I have are the following:

**app_preference.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/your_account">
        <Preference
            app:key="email"
            app:title="@string/title_email" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        app:key="help"
        app:title="@string/help_desk">

        <Preference
            app:key="feedback"
            app:summary="@string/get_help_summary"
            app:title="@string/get_help" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <Preference
        app:key="terms"
        app:title="@string/terms_of_service" />
    <Preference
        app:key="app_version"
        app:title="@string/app_version_label" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**MainActivity**

```
package mypackage;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import mypackage.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_settings,  R.id.test_settings)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);
    }

}
```

**Preference Fragment**

```
package mypackage.ui.testFrag.settings;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import mypackage.R;

public class TestSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_preference, rootKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to have the data available? What do you mean by:  I would like to display the values of my Preferences under their summaries?